# How to write on second sheet of CSV file using TDI/SDI?

Tags: csv, tdi

I want to write some data on second sheet of a CSV file using FileConnector in IBM TDI/SDI.
The first sheet of the same file has data which should not be over written.
Is it possible to do so ?

Any lead will be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Csv files do not have 'sheets'.

They are files with tabular data having only one structure for the whole file, resulting in a single table.